# Is it possible to create Ionic 2 project in Ionic 3 CLI

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

When I do this, I get the message below:

Command :

```
ionic start blank myapp --v2
```

Error :

> [ERROR] Sorry! The --v1 and --v2 flags have been removed.
>           Use the --type option. (ionic start --help)
>           For Ionic Angular projects, try ionic start blank myapp --type=ionic-angular

My Ionic CLI version is :

```
ionic -v
3.3.0
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2 :** You can no longer create Ionic 2 project in Ionic 3 CLI.

As Ionic 2 was not updated & is rewritten using Ionic 3, which uses Angular 4.

So if you create new Ionic project it will use Ionic 3 by default.

---

**Update 1 :** [More Info Available Here](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

With the updates few changes are done in syntax as well :

To create a new project : (You have 3 templates available with Ionic i.e. blank, tabs, sidemenu)

> 1. ionic start {{AppName}} {{TemplateName}} ==> Latest Ionic codebase project
> 2. ionic start {{AppName}} {{TemplateName}} --type ionic1 ==> Ionic v1 project

---

Yes, [You can check this link out](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-cli-v3/)

> ionic start [app-name] [template] --type=ionic1
>
> ionic start [app-name] [template] --type=ionic2
>
> ionic start [app-name] [template] --type=ionic-angular

I have Ionic -v 2.2.2 right now so couldn't test it, so please try and let me know ;)

Comment: ionic start myapp blank --type=ionic2
Error: Unable to find starter type for ionic2

Comment: Are you able to create ionic 1?

Comment: Have you tried changing package.json to ionic 2 components then running project? It might work

Comment: its initial project setup so where i have to find package.json

Comment: As per the ionic documentation here https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start/  , ionic2 is not valid option.

Comment: I think Ionic 2 is deprecated and Ionic 3 is continued.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to specify --v2 for an Ionic 2 project because an Ionic 3 project is just an Ionic 2 project with some new features such as lazy loading and adoption of Angular 4 instead of Angular 2 .Just like Angular 2 and 4 are the same framework ,Ionic 2 and 3 are the same also

Comment: are you sure? I m going to create a project from stretch

Answer (score 0):

You can check in

```
ionic start --list
```

Starters for Ionic 2/3 (--type=ionic-angular)

```
name     | description
-----------------------
tabs     | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
sidemenu | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
blank    | A blank starter project
super    | A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
tutorial | A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
aws      | AWS Mobile Hub Starter
```