# Ionic 1 install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

Hello I want to create Ionic1 project with angular js but when I write command

```
ionic start SotaMobil blank
```

always create ionic 2 with typescript but i want to create ionic1 project how can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you need a `--type=ionic1` flag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366936/will-it-possible-to-create-ionic-2-project-in-ionic-3-cli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [will it possible to create ionic 2 project in ionic 3 CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366936/will-it-possible-to-create-ionic-2-project-in-ionic-3-cli)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ ionic start myApp blank
```

for more details refer:https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/